# What is probability of waiting time greater than 30minutes?

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

> A student arriving at the bank has to visit two counters for service, in sequence. The service time at the first and second counter are exponentially distributed with respective average service times of 10 and 25 minutes. What is the probability that the student's service time will be greater than 30 minutes?If the average service time at both counters is 15 minutes, what is the probability that the student's service time will be greater than 30 minutes?

I'm having a hard time solving this, I know how to solve if there was one counter but if there are n counters(2 in this case) I m not able to understand what to do? I was reading about convolution of exponential random variables but didn't understand how to connect that with this problem.

Comment: Total time is the sum of 2 independent random variables. Do you know how to sum independent random variables?

Comment: @kludg It's not the sum, it's the minimum.

Comment: Let $X$ be the waiting time of the first counter and let $Y$ be the waiting time of the second counter. Now let $Z=\min(X,Y)$. You need to compute $\Pr(Z\geq 30)$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Are you sure it’s meant to be the minimum? I also read it as the sum, based on the wording of “in sequence”: as in they have to wait for one line and then the other. In any case yes, this comes down to writing out the probability of an expression in terms of random variables, so writing out that probability as a double integral is the way I’d go. (just with $Z = X + Y,$ if it happens to be that I understood correctly)

Comment: @StephenDonovan Yes I apologize, that is my mistake. Vatsal, please disregard my comments.

Comment: @kludg Thanks I got it

Comment: Instead of computing PDF of the sum and then integrating to get probability you can directly compute CDF of the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total waiting time is the sum of waiting times at each counter. You can compute CDF of the sum of 2 independent random variables $Z=X_1+X_2$ as follows:
$$F_Z(z)= P(X_1+X_2 \leq z) = \int_0^z P(X_1+X_2\leq z|X_2=x)f_2(x)dx=\int_0^zP(X_1\leq z-x)f_2(x)dx= \int_0^zF_1(z-x)f_2(x)dx$$

The final probability is
$$P= 1-F_z(30)$$